Why helicopters don't use complete tail rotor guard?
Knowing that there is a difference between a tail rotor guard and Fenestron (which also serve as a guard and is present in many helicopter designs), I came across this UltraSport Helicopter and wondered why more helicopters don't use a complete tail rotor guard like it?

Source
Instead the ones that have some guard only use a half guard like the Enstrom280FX or R44?

Source1 Source2

For a small (tiny) helicopter as linked in the first pic, it is entirely possible for a person to be able to interact with the top of the tail rotor. Obviously, if this was spinning, bad things will happen.
On any larger helicopter, the top of the tail rotor arc is out of reach of an adult human. Only the bottom needs to be protected from a tail strike.
It started out as a ducted fan. Control anomalies caused them to ditch the duct. But retained the full ring for protection.
Going to the original manufacturers info:

The tail rotor ducted fan shroud has been replaced with a flat shroud because of an anomaly observed during flight testing which resulted in a reversal of stick position as a function of forward speed.
A more conventional tail rotor has been substituted, though the vertical fin has retained the ring configuration to serve as both a stabilizer as well as a protection system for the tail rotor – something it does very well. The tail boom is a metal construct and the later versions of this assembly have been mounted higher in relation to the fuselage in order to add some ground clearance.

https://www.redbackaviation.com/american-sportscopter-ultrasport-496-helicopter-ultrasport-254-helicopter/
Fun off topic fact: Both the now defunct original manufacturer, American Sportscopter, and the follow on company, Advanced Technologies, Inc.....exist in the business park about 1 mile from my house.

ok makes sense. What about the case of a helicopter taking off on a tight space near electric wires or trees?

@Gabe - For that, you'd also have to worry about the main rotor. Which you can't 'protect'.

You are correct, I didn't realized how long a typical main rotor is, looking at it closely, it almost overlaps the tail rotor.

I think the guard is only there for tail strike protection rather than to prevent people from walking into it. If it's for protecting people, why is there no guard on the rotor side?

The guard that's alternately red and white is so as a warning, not just as decoration.

In short
Let's not mix a rotor guard, a protection against tail strikes, and a ducted fan (one trademark is Fenestron), a different family of propellers. The former belongs to landing safety, the latter belongs to aerodynamic efficiency.
Contrary to the duct of a ducted fan, the rotor guard is regulated, it must prevent the tail rotor to strike the ground when landing, hence the protection is located at the bottom of the rotor, but it often extends forward and aft to prevent contact with walls and obstacles during ground handling.

Rotor guard

Why helicopters don't use complete tail rotor guard?

This guard is not designed to prevent someone to be in contact with the blades. This would require some kind of cage like for boat propellers. Rotors, like propellers on aircraft, have no such requirements.
The role of the tail rotor guard (TRG) is to prevent the blades from striking the ground while maneuvering close to it or when landed. From this Pilot Training Guide:

Tail Rotor Guard: A tubular aluminum tail rotor guard is installed on the aft end of the tailcone. It aids in ground handling and protecting the tail rotor from damage while the helicopter is on the ground.

An example of TRG which cannot protect people, but is enough to prevent a tail rotor strike (Hughes 300C):

Source: Martijn Koetsier at PlaneSpotters.net
Many TRG looks like a half oval protecting the bottom part of the rotor against contact with the ground, but also the rear and bottom parts from contact with the walls and other obstacles to facilitate ground handling.
The TRG design is regulated in relation with the landing:

§ 29.411 Ground clearance: tail rotor guard.

(a) It must be impossible for the tail rotor to contact the landing surface during a normal landing.

(b) If a tail rotor guard is required to show compliance with paragraph (a) of this section—

(1) Suitable design loads must be established for the guard: and

(2) The guard and its supporting structure must be designed to withstand those loads.

Ducted fan

I came across this UltraSport Helicopter and wondered why more helicopters don't use a complete tail rotor guard like it.

The complete ducting seen on some anti-torque rotors is more comparable with an aircraft ducted fan, a different propeller family. This design is found on some rotorcraft, but also on aircraft, on hovercraft and on airships. On helicopters it is known, according to Wikipedia as a "fantail or by the trademark name Fenestron". E.g. on a Eurocopter EC120:

Source.
Note there is a Fenestron, but also the regulated TRG at its bottom.

As referenced in my post's first link, I was aware that the guard was designed to protect the tail rotor, not the person. However, it can't be denied that it can help provide some protection for a person just like a fenestron can also help.

"Rotors are not better protected than propellers." what do you mean by that?

@Gabe Compare helicopter tail rotors to prop driven aircraft propellers. Nothing stops a person from walking into a spinning propeller.

As a point of clarification, do you mean "Not designed for the safety of persons outside the aircraft"?  I would think the one of the purposes of the guard is to prevent harm to occupants of the aircraft that could otherwise occur if the counterbalancing torque supplied by the tail rotor were to suddenly go away while the craft was near the ground.

@mins: In the absence of a guard, could a tail-rotor strike not cause the tail rotor to quickly fly apart and render the aircraft uncontrollable so as to risk harm to the people inside?  Probably not fatal harm, given the altitudes involved, but harm nonetheless?

@mins: If a rotor strike could be potentially fatal to the occupants of an aircraft, any equipment to prevent that would protect the safety of aircraft occupants.  Your answer claims, however, "...this guard is not designed for the safety of persons."  The guard may not be designed for the safety of persons outside the aircraft, but I'm pretty sure that a lot of aircaraft occupants would want to be considered "persons".

As a layperson and non native speaker of English reading that, I can tell that "not designed for the safety of persons" is easily understood as "not designed to prevent people from colliding with a spinning rotor" as intended. Stating that any part of an aircraft is designed with the safety of people (inside or outside the aircraft) in mind seems just stating the obvious.

unreal but it just happened recently: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4wMeTCxZoDk

From the website you linked under "UltraSport Helicopter":
"The tail rotor ducted fan shroud has been replaced with a flat shroud because of an anomaly observed during flight testing which resulted in a reversal of stick position as a function of forward speed."
So this a ducted shroud that had its duct removed, rather than a top-and-bottom-guard.

This is an excellent example of how the development of aircraft can produce unexpected end results even from tried and true solutions.

People walking near an idling helicopter will often duck under the tail boom instead of walking around it. People practically never attempt to climb over the tail boom instead.
Helicopter designers typically take advantage of this behavioral trait to save weight by omitting the unused upper half of the rotor guard.
I can't tell what that thing on the tail of the American Ultrasport is supposed to be. Apparently they couldn't make a duct fly but are reluctant to give it up, so they mounted a sort of a picture of a duct.
